# Needed info for libcurl, cross-platform

Tags: c++, linux, http, winapi, libcurl

I want to implement an auto-update or update notification method for my open-source project.  My searches often lead me to **libcurl**.
I search much about HTTP-libs - and many times I ended up with libcurl ... but can I use it for Linux and Windows together?

My wish is to include only header-files (same header for Linux & WIndows, if possible) and add only OS-spefic lib flags with cmake or visual-studio project files.   That way, I can compile the same code on both platforms. 
Is that possible in general with libcurl?  If yes, how do I do that directly?

Comment: libcurl is c not c++. Are you talking about the binding https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp? Were you unable to find the information you need there?

Comment: @prune Please leave your edit comments in the edit summary box, not in the comment box. And you certainly don't need to put them in *both* places!

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks.  I had to refresh the page during my edit, and the original edit comments disappeared.  Apparently, they got saved.  As for the (now deleted) comment, I obviously goofed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

An application can use libcurl on both Linux and Windows with the source code parts that do the HTTP transfers being identical. libcurl provides the same API and it works the same on a vast amount of different operating systems.